# Backbone.js offline not saving to local storage after fetch

Tags: backbone.js, coffeescript

Hi hope someone can help me,

Im trying to use backbone offline (https://github.com/Ask11/backbone.offline), I can manage to fetch to my server through backbone offline sync method but it doesnt store in local, here are some parts of my code:

```
define ['Backbone'
, 'Backbone.OffLine'
, 'models/requestOffer/RequestOfferModel']
,(Backbone
, OffLine
, RequestOfferModel) ->

  class RequestOfferCollection extends Backbone.Collection
    model: RequestOfferModel
    urlRoot: window.generalRootlUrl
    sync:  Backbone.Sync;
    initialize: ->
      console.log 'Request Collection init'
      @storage = new Offline.Storage('RequestOfferCollection', @, autoPush: true)
    url: ->
      api ='/api/v1/requestoffer/?format=json'
      return @urlRoot+api
```

And this is how i do the call

```
  @reqOfferCol.fetch
        local: false
        data:
          'party': 1
          'estado': @list2Show
        success: (resp) =>
          console.log 'Success'
        error: (error) =>
          console.log 'Error en fectch!!!'
```

I add the updated_at property to my model.

Im also using backbone.localstorage, can this conflicts with backbone.offline, 
I was careful assigning the sync methods to each model.

Thank u so much.

Answer (score 1):

Wild guess, but where you set the sync method, try to replace `Backbone.Sync` (with a capital S) with `Backbone.sync` instead (with lowercase s) and see if that helps.